# GPLライブラリをリンクしたプログラムに対する対応方法

Tags: linux, gpl

仕事でLinuxを使っているのですが、使用しているライブラリがGPLライセンスであることに気づきました。

GPLライブラリを静的リンクしたプログラムは、GPLが適用されるという解説サイトが複数あり、
このままでは今開発しているプログラムはGPL適用になるのだろうと思っています。
ですが、いまいち腑の落ちておりませんので質問させてください。

1. GPLライセンスのライブラリソースコードを改変してリンクした場合に、GPL適用となるのではなく、GPLライセンスのライブラリを静的リンクしたら、リンクしたプログラムはGPLライセンス適用となるという理解であってますか？
2. Linuxで開発しているとGPLライブラリのリンクをすべて避けて開発することはかなり難しと感じています。一般的に世の中のLinuxで開発している商用ソフトウェアは、GPLライセンスを避けて開発しているものが多いのでしょうか？GPLライセンスを適用して、ソースコードを公開しているのでしょうか？
3. ソースコード公開は要求されてから行えばよいのでしょうか？

私の感覚だと世の中にはもっとGPL適用の商用ソフトウェアが溢れているはずなのに、ソースコードが公開されているなんて話をそれほど聞かないのでGPLライセンスの解説が納得できないのです。
初歩的な質問で申し訳ありません。

Comment: 法務部門にご相談されるのがベターかと思いますが、[IPA(情報処理推進機構)](http://www.ipa.go.jp/osc/osslegal.html)よりGPLライセンスの解釈に関する情報が色々と提供されています。ご参考にしてください。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> GPLライセンスのライブラリソースコードを改変してリンクした場合に、GPL適用となるのではなく、GPLライセンスのライブラリを静的リンクしたら、リンクしたプログラムはGPLライセンス適用となるという理解であってますか？

改変をしておらずとも静的リンクをしたソフトは開示範囲となります。
動的リンクの場合は開示範囲ではないという「見解があり」ます。
事実後述の企業はAndroidのソフト全体のソースコードを開示しているわけではなく、静的リンク範囲のみ公開しています。

> Linuxで開発しているとGPLライブラリのリンクをすべて避けて開発することはかなり難しと感じています。一般的に世の中のLinuxで開発している商用ソフトウェアは、GPLライセンスを避けて開発しているものが多いのでしょうか？

私見が入りますが、同様機能でGPLライセンスとそうでないものがあればGPLライセンスのものは避けて開発するかと思います。
あるいはGPLライセンスが伝播しないような方法(動的リンクの範囲内にとどめる等)をとるかと思います。

> ソースコード公開は要求されてから行えばよいのでしょうか？

基本的にはソフトをPublishする上で公開は必要になります。
ただ・・・・古めの情報になりますが、下記にまとめられている通りGPLライセンスを遵守していない企業も多くあるようです。
http://www.codon.org.uk/~mjg59/android_tablets/index.html

> ソースコードが公開されているなんて話をそれほど聞かないので

http://k-tai.sharp.co.jp/support/developers/oss/
http://android-dev.kyocera.co.jp/source/
http://spf.fmworld.net/fujitsu/c/develop/sp/android/
等、基本的に公開義務のあるものは各企業公開しています。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。ソース公開している企業も多いのですね。調査不足でした。やはり、静的リンクしたらGPL適用で、動的リンクはグレーのようですね。動的リンクの範囲にできないか検討するとともに、法務に相談してみます。

Answer (score 5):

基本的にはH.Hさんの回答と同じ見解です。少し補足させてもらいます。

- GPLと言っても、GPLv2、GPLv3、LGPLv2、LGPLv3 と何種類かあります。
  LGPLv2、LGPLv3の場合、動的リンクを行うプログラムにはLGPLv2、LGPLv3は適用しなくてもよいです。つまりソースコード公開は不要です。
  ただし、リバースエンジニアリングの禁止ができないです。
- GPLライブラリでも例外条項を含むものもあります。代表的なものですと`libgcc`(gccでビルドするプログラムのスタートアップライブラリ)があります。(リンクしてもGPLの対象外としてよい)
- GPLプログラムのソースコード公開は、そのプログラムを入手した人に行えばよいので、入手していない人にまで公開する義務はなかったと認識してます。